# C: binary trees, memory allocation

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, binary-search-tree

So I'm trying to build a binary tree in C using structs and all that jazz. So far, I've got the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <signal.h>

typedef struct treeNode {
    int value;
    struct treeNode *left;
    struct treeNode *right;
} node;

node *top = NULL;

static node *addNode(int e, node *n);
static void printTree(node *n);

static node *addNode(int e, node *n) {
    if(top == NULL) {
        top = malloc(sizeof(node));
        top->value = e;
        top->left = NULL;
        top->right = NULL;
        return top;
    } else if (n != NULL) {
        if(e <= n->value) {
            if(n->left == NULL) {
                n->left = addNode(e, n->left);
            } else {
                (void) addNode(e, n->left); 
            }
        } else {
            if(n->right == NULL) {
                n->right = addNode(e, n->right);
            } else {
                (void) addNode(e, n->right);
            }
        }
    } else if(n == NULL) {
        n = malloc(sizeof(node));
        n->value = e;
        n->left = NULL;
        n->right = NULL;
        return n;
    }
    return n;
}

static void printTree(node *n) {
    if(n != NULL) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%d, ", n->value);
        if(n->left != NULL) {
            printTree(n->left);
        }
        if(n->right != NULL) {
            printTree(n->right);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        addNode(1, top);
        addNode(2, top);
        addNode(0, top);
        addNode(3, top);
        printTree(top);
return 0;
}
```

It's missing stuff like about everything other than adding nodes and printing the tree, but that's where I have questions already. What I do get is some odd behaviour in the addNode function:
Originally, I had the first if clause set up as

```
if(n == NULL) {
    n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->value = e;
    n->left = NULL;
    n->right = NULL;
    return n;
}
```

Which didn't work out at all - no new nodes were created due to that. The way it is now, it's working out the way it has to - and I don't really understand why it behaves like that. When I call the addNode function for the first time, I'm giving it the top pointer as a parameter anyways, so it should check if it's null (which it should be at that point) and should just allocate some memory for it. It does not happen, though. And I don't get why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several points here. First let start by details: your `printTree()` is too complicated. As you check for NULL value when entering the function you don't have to check it again for left/right:

```
void printTree(node *n) {
  if (n == NULL) { return; }  // just leave
  printTree(n->left);
  printf("%d\n", n->value);
  printTree(n->right);
}
```

Note that the order of printing value, left and right will change the output. In this example it will be printed from low to high values.

Now for your `addNode()` you don't need a global `top` value. You give the `top` to your function and get the new one with returned value (`top = addNode(val, top);`. Having this global value just can lead to bad code when mixing `n` and `top` access.
And the function can be more simple:

```
node *addNode(int val, node *n) {
  if (n == NULL) {  // just allocate a new one
    n = malloc(sizeof(node));  // add check for failure here, of course
    n->left = n->right = NULL; // it is a leaf, no child
    n->value = val;
    return(n);  // return the node for caller
  }
  // ok, we are on a node, check on which side we need to insert
  if (val < n->value) {
    // to the left: it may be replaced (if created)
    n->left = addNode(val, n->left);
  } else {
    // same, for right
    n->right = addNode(val, n->right);
  }
  // return the node so that top=addNode(val,top) always works
  return(n);
}
```

You can prevent passing+getting node using a pointer to the node, but then you'll have to well understand dereferencing pointers. It could be:

```
void addNode(int val, node **n) {
  if (*n == NULL) {  // just allocate a new one
    *n = malloc(sizeof(node));  // add check for failure here, of course
    (*n)->left = (*n)->right = NULL; // it is a leaf, no child
    (*n)->value = val;
    return;  // return, the node 'n' is still modified
  }
  // ok, we are on a node, check on which side we need to insert
  if (val < (*n)->value) {
    // to the left: it may be replaced (if created)
    (*n)->left = addNode(val, (*n)->left);
  } else {
    // same, for right
    (*n)->right = addNode(val, (*n)->right);
  }
  // leave function (return not needed), node unchanged
  return;
}
```

Then you will call this function this way:

```
int main(void) {
  node *top = NULL;  // must be initialized

  addNode(3, &top);
  addNode(1, &top);
  addNode(5, &top);
  printNode(top);
  (…)
```

Comment: Note: `(*n)->left` (and the same for right and value)

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the first node to `top`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    top = addNode(1, top);
    addNode(2, top);
    addNode(0, top);
    addNode(3, top);
    printTree(top);
    return 0;
}
```

With your original `if` clause, `top` was not getting updated. You were just returning `n`.

Comment: No, `top` was being set in `addNode`.  look at the call to `malloc`.  `top` is global.  So this won't make any difference.

Comment: This code is to make his original attempt work where he put `if n == NULL` first and was not setting `top` at all.

Comment: oh, ok, sorry I misunderstood